# Flutter ListView with Row Property of space between

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, row, hybrid-mobile-app

Looking for Flutter Listview with horizontal scroll and Row Property of space between(automatically adjust items with equal spaces) if the item count is less(can fit in on the screen) and slide if the item count is more

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by creating keys for each element in the List, then calculating it size in runtime.

If the size of all the elements together is more than the Screen Width, We can have a Row, otherwise, we need to use ListView

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double elementsWidth;
  List paymentMethodsList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    paymentMethodsList = [
      {
        'paymentName': 'UPI Transfer',
        "key": GlobalKey(),
      },
      {
        'paymentName': 'NEFT Transfer',
        "key": GlobalKey(),
      },
      {
        'paymentName': 'IMPS Transfer',
        "key": GlobalKey(),
      },
      {
        'paymentName': 'RTGS Transfer',
        "key": GlobalKey(),
      },
      {
        'paymentName': 'UPI Collect',
        "key": GlobalKey(),
      },
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  void postFrameCallback(_) {
    double widthOfElements = 0;
    int numberOfElementsParsed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < paymentMethodsList.length; i++) {
      var context = paymentMethodsList[i]['key'].currentContext;
      if (context == null) return;
      numberOfElementsParsed++;
      widthOfElements += context.size.width;
    }
    if (numberOfElementsParsed == paymentMethodsList.length) {
      setState(() {
        elementsWidth = 100 + widthOfElements;
        print(elementsWidth);
      });
    }
    // if (oldSize == newSize) return;

    // oldSize = newSize;
    // widget.onChange(newSize);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(postFrameCallback);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      // appBar: buildAppBar(),
      body: buildPage(),
    );
  }

  buildPage() => Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          buildPaymentListWidget(),
          // SizedBox(
          //   height: 20,
          // ),
        ],
      );

  Container buildPaymentListWidget() {
    return Container(
      height: 90,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
      child: elementsWidth != null &&
              elementsWidth < MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
          ? Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < paymentMethodsList.length; i++)
                  buildPaymentItemWidget(i)
              ],
            )
          : ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: false,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                width: 15,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return buildPaymentItemWidget(index);
              },
              itemCount: paymentMethodsList.length,
            ),
    );
  }

  Container buildPaymentItemWidget(int index) {
    return Container(
      key: paymentMethodsList[index]['key'],
      child: Text(
        paymentMethodsList[index]['paymentName'],
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code with Scroll Direction for wrap you can use Expanded.

```
ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: numbers.length,
               itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Container(
                        child: Center(child: "text", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 36.0),)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
            }),
```

For equal separator user ListView.separator like this

```
ListView.separated(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(child: Text("Index $index")),
      ),
)
```

Comment: Hi @muhammad-ashir, The question was a little different. Added more detail to the question with image. I am looking for something like a list view which is capable of adjusting the elements on the screen with even spacing when the elements can be fit on the screen, and have expanded property when the elements are more and overlapping